# Cloudflare not caching files even when headers are "Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400"

Tags: node.js, nginx, caching, cloudflare

When i use the curl command all the headers are correct but files are not caching as

> CF-Cache-Status: MISS

is shown by curl command .

```
> < HTTP/1.1 200 OK < Date: Sat, 02 Jun 2018 05:57:28 GMT <
> Content-Type: image/png < Content-Length: 2293 < Connection:
> keep-alive < Set-Cookie:
> __cfduid=d3cf179afd212660124585350d19e88c81527919048; expires=Sun, 02-Jun-19 05:57:28 GMT; path=/; domain=.mayan.cf; HttpOnly <
> X-Powered-By: Express < Accept-Ranges: bytes < Cache-Control: public,
> max-age=86400 < Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Jun 2018 15:39:06 GMT < ETag:
> W/"8f5-163bc009a0c" < CF-Cache-Status: MISS < Expires: Sun, 03 Jun
> 2018 05:57:28 GMT < Server: cloudflare < CF-RAY: 4247aec4300930f6-SIN
> <  { [1905 bytes data]
> * Connection #0 to host mayan.cf left intact
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudflare uses some heuristics to try to guess, based on the request alone, whether the content is static (cacheable) or dynamic. If it guesses wrong at request time, it won't cache the response. You can disable this heuristic by setting the Page Rule "Cache Level" to "Cache Everything" -- then Cloudflare will assume that the response will always be cacheable.

Try setting that page rule and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this Page Rules really helped.

Answer (score 0):

> If the Cache-Control header is set to "private", "no-store",
>   "no-cache",  or "max-age=0", or if **there is a cookie** in the response,
>   then Cloudflare will **not cache** the resource.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/202775670-How-Do-I-Tell-Cloudflare-What-to-Cache-

Comment: I have already read it see the output :-Cache-Control: public,
> max-age=86400 in question .

Comment: @gautamkumar see the output `Set-Cookie: __cfduid=...`

Comment: @AlexeyTen That cookie was added by Cloudflare itself. That doesn't count.